# How do I make my code set focus to a specific button in a jQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have code to open a `jQueryUI` dialog with two buttons (<kbd>OK</kbd>, and <kbd>Cancel</kbd>). When the dialog opens, I want the OK button to have focus by default. After that, when I press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, it should perform the actions associated with the <kbd>OK</kbd> button. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
open: function() {
        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq
(1)').focus();
        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq
(0)').blur();
},
```

Comment: see this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793592/jquery-ui-dialog-button-focus
it will be help full to you..

Comment: @PoonamBhatt if u done with u r problem....than make it as answer..so that anyone can refer it....