# Want to see source without clicking any key

Tags: css, jquery-ui, firefox, firebug

In my web application I see a strange behavior.A strange border appears on "ok" button of conform light box(created using jquery-ui dialog). Now I want to use firebug or view source to debug it more.But as soon as I click strange border disappears.Is there any way to "view source" without clicking any key(left/right) in firefox/chrome?

Comment: That sounds like a focus `outline`.

Comment: Here I got [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793592/jquery-ui-dialog-button-focus).

Answer (score 4):

Both Chrome and Firebug allow you to set the hover/focus state in the developer tools.

---

Here's how to do it in the Chrome Developer Tools:

[image: Chrome Developer Tools hover/focus]

---

And here's how to do it in Firebug:

[image: Firebug hover/focus]