# jQuery - When I open a UI Dialog, the focus is happening on the 2nd Input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I searched all through my code and can't find anything that is telling jQuery dialog to focus on the 2nd input box. Any ideas on how to debug this, so I can figure out where the focus event is coming from?

Thanks

Comment: Any chance to see your code? And even better provide a scenario illustrating the problem on http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the tabindex of your inputs.
See this helpful and partially related [StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202079/prevent-jquery-ui-dialog-from-setting-focus-to-first-textbox).