# How to avoid automatic focus on first input field when popping a HTML form as a JQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder, autofocus, input-field

I have seen similar questions on SO, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202079/prevent-jquery-ui-dialog-from-setting-focus-to-first-textbox), which is old. I read and followed links, but it is unclear whether there is a proper solution to this issue today.

My bottom issue is that I am using HTML's `placeholder="..."` on the input fields. By focusing automatically on the first field, its placeholder is not visible to the user anymore.

**EDIT**

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id='LOGIN_FORM' title="Login">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="login_id" required="required"
                           placeholder="Enter user ID" /><br />
        <input type="password" name="login_pwd" required="required"
                           placeholder="Enter password" /><br />
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
$("#login").click(function() { 
    $("#LOGIN_FORM").dialog({ modal: true }, { buttons: [
    {
            text: "Ok",
            click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    ] });
});
```

Comment: The page you linked to answers your question perfectly.

Comment: @mblase75 Sorry, but I don't see how the approved answer (or others) solve this issue (I am new to JS).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution is to set `tabindex="-1"` on **ALL** input fields to keep HTML placeholders visible.

Comment: defeats the purpose of navigating form through tabs

Comment: This breaks accessibility. Not a viable tradeoff.

Comment: This aswer is as good as saying "dont show your popup at all"

Comment: I agree, that this is not the best for accessibility. In my case it was the best (and right) solution though, as I know that my website will be only used on touch devices and I can ignore keyboard-related navigation

Answer (score 27):

What I did was I created an extra input and made it invisible (`style="display:none"`) then gave it the property `autofocus="true"` put this at the end of your dialog content so it wont mess with anything. it should look like this:

```
        <div><!--dialog div-->
           <button></button>
           <button></button> 
          <input type="hidden" autofocus="true" />
        </div>
```

Comment: I followed your solution but it has one great disadvantage - if you bind a _blur_ event to the first input on form (the one that had been auto-focused before) it will be fired right after page loads (try with alert() or console.log()). To avoid this type of issues try to use input of _text_ type instead of _hidden_, ie.: `<input type="text" autofocus />`.

Comment: I also had another issue with Chrome, it works first time, but when I close the dialog and reopen it, it ignores it

Comment: Thanks buddy. You saved my day.

Answer (score 15):

Adding this tag as the first input field on the page works for me.

```
<input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" style="display:none" />
```

No need for javascript and keeps the tab order if you want to use the tab key to move through the fields.

(Tested on Chrome > 65, Firefox > 59 and Edge)

Comment: That great you save the time.

Answer (score 9):

I ended up doing this:

```
<input type="text" style="position: fixed; left: -10000000px;" disabled/>
```

Comment: putting this as first field works for me, it doesn't fire a blur on the other real fields

Answer (score 5):

In my case  solution with display: none or type=hidden did not help. You can use

```
<div style="max-width: 0; max-height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <input autofocus="true" />
</div>
```

as first input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('input[name="login_id"]').blur(); 
});
```

This if you find it hard to trace the bug why autofocus is set into your first input field of the form. Make sure to insert this code before the closing `</body>` body tag of your document.

Comment: problem with this approach is if you have an event listener for onblur on the input (ie, do an auto-search upon blurring the element)

Answer (score 2):

Set `tabindex=0` on the `form`. This fixes your issue and should be fine as far as accessibility is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
<input type="text" name="fake[email]" style="height:1px;width:1px;overflow:hidden;clip:rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);border:0;outline:none;padding:0;margin:0;color:transparent;" tab-index="-1" aria-hidden="true" value=".">
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue on my Laravel + Bootstrap setup using below code in my blade template:

```php
{{ Form::text(null, null, ['class' => 'd-none', 'autofocus']) }}
```

Answer (score -4):

Without JQuery and JavaScript, we can give a CSS-only solution.

1. remove all focus's outline

   ```
   :focus {
       outline: 0;
   }
   ```
2. add the new focus's outline

   ```
   :link:focus, :visited:focus {
       outline: none;
   }
   ```

Comment: Although this will "appear" to resolve the issue, it creates several more accessibility issues :) http://www.outlinenone.com/