# How to remove initial auto focus of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, css, autofocus

I am wondering how to remove the automatic focus which automatically happens to the first anchor tag on page load.

I am not looking to disable all focus ability which is pretty much all I was able to find solutions to while researching this question. The focus should still apply and show when an anchor is *clicked*.

Here is the css (scss in this case) for the focus itself, which I want to remain.

```
&:focus {
     outline:3px solid #51ace9
}
```

I have tried doing something like this to get rid of the auto focus on page load:

```
window.onload= function() {
  var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('my_class')
  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].blur();
  }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Can someone suggest a proper solution?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `tabindex`  attribute to be 0 or -1?

Comment: @Elena I have tried this, but I don't see how this will affect the autofocus. Doesn't `tabindex` just affect the way its tabbed through via the keyboard?

Comment: what browser are you testing on? I'm on Chrome 47 and it doesn't autofocus anything. So I'm guessing either you have a script that is focussing something or it's a browser specific thing (your blur code works for me). I've been playing with this: https://jsfiddle.net/07c6Lw1d/

Comment: @Dear1ofGdBear, that was just a guess

Comment: Take a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827004/how-to-avoid-automatic-focus-on-first-input-field-when-popping-a-html-form-as-a

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function({  
 $("a").blur() ;

    });
```