# Unable to remove Autofocus in ui-dialog

Tags: jquery, autofocus

The first element in my jQuery UI Dialog is an input, which when selected opens a datepicker...

How can I disable this input from being selected first?

Comment: Do you have a test page? or Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing your case

Comment: it's a universal probelm with ui-dialog.

Answer (score 47):

Add the following code before you call dialog. This will clear out the autofocus code. It works for me in jquery 2.0.3.

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype._focusTabbable = function(){};
```

Comment: thank you - this helped my problem of the dialog always going back to the first element, not just on open

Comment: great. I currently need to mix jqueryUI and bootstrap, and the use a lot of dialogs without inputs, which caused all my first dialog buttons to have the hover state, and hence look broken. This solves that issue

Comment: It requires jQuery _UI_ 1.10 or higher

Comment: It's kludgey, but it does the trick nicely. Thanks for saving me what would have likely been a tonne of time.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works for me

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was crazy!

Comment: Warning: when the dialog pops up, pressing the Escape key won't close the dialog (until you focus the dialog).

Comment: Thank you! this helped my problem to focus on other div

Answer (score 9):

Very simple, just trigger the `blur` event on the input elements when the dialog box opens.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $("input").blur();
    }
});
```

#### Check it out *[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/8VbEU/1/)*

#### [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/8VbEU/2/) with datepicker

<sub>***NOTE:*** For more in-depth solution to this problem, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1202501/295264) answer too.</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work when dealing with a dialog that has autoOpen: false.
http://jsfiddle.net/8VbEU/134/

Answer (score 4):

JQuery sets the autofocus on the first input that is found.
So play it sneaky by creating a "fake" input at the first line of your dialog like that:

```
<input type='text' size='1' style='position:relative;top:-500px;' />
```

So your input will be out of the window and have the focus. Problem solved for me ;p