# Get the jquery ui timepicker to not auto-open in a modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, timepicker

I'm trying to have a time picker ([this one](http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/)) to not auto-open when it's inside a modal dialog.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/9DwED/) a js fiddle demonstrating the problem. If I have a text box outside of the modal, and call .timepicker on it, it doesn't open right up. If I open up the modal dialog that contains another timepicker, it's already open. Anyone know of a way I can work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add tabindex="-1" to the input field in the modal. After some digging I learned that jQuery dialogue will select the first input field. When the input field gains focus it activates the timepicker. Here are some interesting reads on the topic:

[Prevent jQuery UI dialog from setting focus to first textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202079/prevent-jquery-ui-dialog-from-setting-focus-to-first-textbox)

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4731

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Kinda strange that jQuery doesn't have a workaround for that built in.