# hide datepicker when dialog close jquery

Tags: jquery, dialog, datepicker

I am trying to hide the datepicker when i close the dialog

here is what i used

```
$("#dialog_edit_calendar").dialog({
    close: function () {
        $('#edit-calendar-form')[0].reset();
        $("#calendardate").datepicker("hide");
    }
});
```

I also tried

```
$("#calendardate").datepicker("remove");
```

but it fails !

here is my html

```
 <input class="required" maxlength="10" type="text" data-error-type="inline" name="calendardate"
                id="calendardate" onchange="showDaytoSelectedDate1()"/>
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/VytfY/229) is the example fiddle

my scenario is when i open dialog the datepicker should not open

Comment: I believe it's `destroy` instead, remove doesn't seem to be part of the API http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy (also hide is)

Comment: Can you give us some additional infos ? Your html-code perhaps ?

Comment: I also used destroy but if i use that when i open my dialog again the datepicker is not opening

Comment: which version of jQuery UI are you using,,, i tried with 'hide' and i works in jsFiddle below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VytfY/227/) .

```
    close: function () {
        $("#datepicker1").datepicker('hide'); // your datepicker ID ..
        $("#datepicker2").datepicker('hide'); // your datepicker ID ..
        ....
        .....
    }
```

**UPDATE:** to prevent focus on first input when jQuery UI modal is invoked.
Here is the issue discussed with multiple solutions. [Prevent jQuery UI dialog from setting focus to first textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202079/prevent-jquery-ui-dialog-from-setting-focus-to-first-textbox)

Updated [jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/VytfY/230/)

```
 $("#dialog").dialog({

  ...
  open: function(){
      $('input:first').blur();
      $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide(); // required to hide datepicker container DIV immediately.
      $("#datepicker1").datepicker('hide'); // required to hide datepicker.
  }
  ...
  });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VytfY/229/     this is my scenario and thanks for your fiddle

Comment: @rp3220 here is your code updated http://jsfiddle.net/VytfY/230/ . i have added code in open:function(){ ... } of dialog

Comment: @rp3220 the problem is basically with focus set on first input element when dialog is opened.. here is issue discussed,, there are many solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202079/prevent-jquery-ui-dialog-from-setting-focus-to-first-textbox

Answer (score 0):

$("#calendardate").css('display', 'none');

or

$("#calendardate").attr('style', 'display: none;');

should work

Comment: thanks ! but Sorry thats hiding the input box i want to hide the datepicker not the input box

Comment: Do you want to hide it after selecting a date? or on custom requirements

Comment: In that case use:  $('#dialog_edit_calendar').dialog('close')

Answer (score 0):

If you use [hide](http://jqueryui.com/hide/) you can even use other hiding effects effects.

```
$("#calendardate").hide();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sL8t1dha/)

[slide hide](http://jsfiddle.net/sL8t1dha/1/)

Comment: thanks ! but Sorry thats hiding the input box i want to hide the datepicker not the input box

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dialog_edit_calendar").dialog({
open: function () {
    $('input:first').blur();
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
    $("#calendardate").datepicker("hide");
   }
});
```

@Dave gave me the answer

That  to hide datepicker while i am opening dialog