# What exactly can cause an "HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3"-Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, domexception

How exactly does it relate to jQuery? I know the library uses native javascript functions internally, but what exactly is it trying to do whenever such a problem appears?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

It means you've tried to insert a DOM node into a place in the DOM tree where it cannot go. The most common place I see this is on Safari which doesn't allow the following:

```
document.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
```

Generally, this is just a mistake where this was actually intended:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
```

Other causes seen in the wild (summarized from comments):

- You are attempting to append a node to itself
- You are attempting to append null to a node
- You are attempting to append a node to a text node.
- Your HTML is invalid (e.g. failing to close your target node)
- The browser thinks the HTML you are attempting to append is XML (fix by adding `<!doctype html>` to your injected HTML, or specifying the content type when fetching via XHR)

Comment: The error also occurs when you try and append a node to itself. I just ran into this one myself :-)

Comment: I just got this trying to add a null to an element (and a totally unrelated tip - always make sure your functions return the thing you wrote them to return :P)

Comment: I saw this when one of the closing tags was missing out of the target.

Comment: IE(9) may throw this error when using jQuery to append AJAX results. Avoid this by using `response.xml` where available. For example, `$(e).append(response.xml || $(response));`

Comment: Got this when I changed from jQuery (desktop) to zepto on Android. Switched back.

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting this error due to a jquery ajax call $.ajax

Then you may need to specify what the ***dataType*** is coming back from the server. I have fixed the response a lot using this simple property.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "URL_HERE",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response) {
        $('#ELEMENT').html(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: single code base for web/phonegap, refactored to dynamically loading template using answer by koorchik at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366733/external-template-in-underscore. worked in desktop browser, did not work in mobile browser or native app.  this solution did the trick.

Comment: Same issue here, weirdly only in iOS 5. Specifying dataType worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Specifically with jQuery you can run into this issue if forget the carets around the html tag when creating elements:

```
 $("#target").append($("div").text("Test"));
```

Will raise this error because what you meant was

```
 $("#target").append($("<div>").text("Test"));
```

Answer (score 3):

This error can occur when you try to insert a node into the DOM which is invalid HTML, which can be something as subtle as an incorrect attribute, for example:

```
// <input> can have a 'type' attribute
var $input = $('<input/>').attr('type', 'text');
$holder.append($input);  // OK

// <div> CANNOT have a 'type' attribute
var $div = $('<div></div>').attr('type', 'text');
$holder.append($div);   // Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3
```

Answer (score 2):

@Kelly Norton is right in his answer that `The browser thinks the HTML you are attempting to append is XML` and suggests `specifying the content type when fetching via XHR`.

It's true however you sometimes use third party libraries that you are not going to modify. It's JQuery UI in my case. Then you should provide the right `Content-Type` in the response instead of overriding the response type on JavaScript side. Set your `Content-Type` to `text/html` and you are fine.

In my case, it was as easy as renaming the `file.xhtml` to `file.html` - application server had some extension to MIME types mappings out of the box. When content is dynamic, you can set the content type of response somehow (e.g. `res.setContentType("text/html")` in Servlet API).

Answer (score 1):

You can see these questions

[Getting HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR when using Javascript to recursively generate a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934049/getting-hierarchy-request-err-when-using-javascript-to-recursively-generate-a-nes)

or

[jQuery UI Dialog with ASP.NET button postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757232/jquery-ui-dialog-with-asp-net-button-postback)

The conclusion is

when you try to use function append, you should use new variable, like this example

```
jQuery(function() {
   var dlg = jQuery("#dialog").dialog({ 
                        draggable: true, 
                        resizable: true, 
                        show: 'Transfer', 
                        hide: 'Transfer', 
                        width: 320, 
                        autoOpen: false, 
                        minHeight: 10, 
                        minwidth: 10 
          });
  dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
});
```

In the example above, uses the var "dlg" to run the function appendTo.
Then error “HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR" will not come out again.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when using the Google Chrome extension Sidewiki.  Disabling it resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add one more specific answer here because it was a 2 hour search for the answer...

I was trying to inject a  tag into a document.  The html was like this:

```
<map id='imageMap' name='imageMap'>
  <area shape='circle' coords='55,28,5' href='#' title='1687.01 - 0 percentile' />
</map>
```

If you notice, the  tag is closed in the preceding example (`<area/>`).  This was not accepted in Chrome browsers.  [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp) seems to think it should be closed, and I could not find the official spec on this tag, but it sure doesn't work in Chrome.  Firefox will not accept it with `<area/>` or `<area></area>` or `<area>`.  Chrome must have `<area>`.  IE accepts anything.

**Anyway, this error can be because your HTML is not correct.**

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but I've encountered another cause of the problem which others might find helpful. I was getting the error with Google Analytics trying to append itself to an HTML comment. The offending code:

```
document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(ga);
```

This was causing the error because my first element was an HTML comment (namely a Dreamweaver template code).

```
<!-- #BeginTemplate "/Templates/default.dwt.php" -->
```

I modified the offending code to something admittedly not bulletproof, but better:

```
document.documentElement.firstChild.nodeType===1 ? document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(ga) : document.documentElement.lastChild.appendChild(ga);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run into this problem while trying to append a node into another window in Internet Explorer, try using the HTML inside the node instead of the node itself.

```
myElement.appendChild(myNode.html());
```

IE doesn't support appending nodes to another window.

Comment: Did you actually try this? Even in Chrome i am getting TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.(…). Thats because .html() is of type string and appendChild is expecting type Node.

Answer (score 1):

This ERROR happened to me in IE9 when I tried to appendChild an  dynamically to a  which already existed in a window A. Window A would create a child window B. In window B after some user action a function would run and do an appendChild on the form element in window A using `window.opener.document.getElementById('formElement').appendChild(input);`

This would throw an error. Same with creating the input element using `document.createElement('input');` in the child window, passing it as a parameter to the `window.opener` window A, and there do the append. Only if I created the input element in the same window where I was going to append it, it would succeed without errors.

Thus my conclusion (please verify): no element can be dynamically created (using `document.createElement`) in one window, and then appended (using `.appendChild`) to an element in another window (without taking maybe a particular extra step I missed to ensure it is not considered XML or something). This fails in IE9 and throws the error, in FF this works fine though.

PS. I don't use jQuery.

Comment: Thanks to your pointer, i figured out a way around this. Please see the answer I posted if you're interested interested.

Answer (score 0):

I got that error because I forgot to clone my element.

```
// creates an error
clone = $("#thing");
clone.appendTo("#somediv");

// does not
clone = $("#thing").clone();
clone.appendTo("#somediv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this can come up is that you are appending before the element is ready e.g.

```
<body>

<script>
document.body.appendChild(foo);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this case, you'll need to move the script after the . Not entirely sure if that's kosher, but moving the script after the body doesn't seem to help :/

Instead of moving the script, you can also do the appending in an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference.

IE will block appending any element created in a different window context from the window context that the element is being appending to.

e.g

```
var childWindow = window.open('somepage.html');

//will throw the exception in IE
childWindow.document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));

//will not throw exception in IE
childWindow.document.body.appendChild(childWindow.document.createElement('div'));
```

I haven't figured out how to create a dom element with jQuery using a different window context yet.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error in IE9 if I had disabled script debugging (Internet Explorer) option. If I enable script debugging I don't see the error and the page works fine. This seems odd what is the DOM exception got to do with debugging either enabled or disabled.