# Unspecified error DOM IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, popup

I'm building application using pop-ups. I'm getting new information with Ajax in the main page and updating the popup page. In the side window (pop-up) I've got a table and when new data is received I'm just adding row in this table. In FF, Chrome and Opera that is working pretty well but when I try to append child (no matter if I'm using jquery or not) IE gives me a Unspecified error. I'm trying to append the child directly to the table like that:

```
var tableHeader = this.config.newResultsWindow.document.getElementById('newResultsTableHeader');
tableHeader.appendChild(newRow);
```

When I'm using just innerHTML (for example `this.config.newResultsWindow.document.body.innerHTML = updatedTable`) everything is OK but the table's content is very big and I cant write it all every time.

What can I do?

Comment: What's the type of the `'#newResultsTableHeader'` element? Table?

Comment: Provide a debuggable testcase please....

Comment: //It's thead element. This is how I'm creating the row:

  buildTableRow: function (data) {
   var row = '<tr class="resultRow">', width;
   for (var child in data) {    
    row += '<td>' + data[child] + '</td>';
   }
   row += '</tr>';     
   return $(row);
  },

//And appending it:

newRes.parentNode.insertBefore(row[0], newRes.nextSibling );

//Here the newRes is a thead element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't allow the moving of nodes between different document's , so a node created in document A cannot be inserted to document B

Comment: Does IE support `document.adoptNode`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.adoptNode ... it's DOM Level 3 so I assume not.

Comment: Is there an alternative for that in previous IE versions?

Comment: Yes, there is an easy way that works in all browsers. When creating the row using `$(row)` provide as 2nd argument to $ the document-object of the popup-window, so the row will be created by the popup-document and you don't have issues with different documents. See the fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/J9KLL/** (it uses an iframe instead of a popup, but it's the same problem with different documents)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried catching the error, it might tell you more than 'Unspecified':

```
try {
    tableHeader.appendChild(newRow);
} catch(error) {
    alert(error);
}
```

I hope it helps,
Rob

Comment: It's gave me "DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3)".

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256394/what-exactly-can-cause-an-hierarchy-request-err-dom-exception-3-error

Comment: Just saw Dr. Molle's answer, it makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Found something that worked for me. Try appending the HTML inside of the newRow variable:

```
tableHeader.appendChild(newRow.html());
```