# External template in Underscore

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I use [Underscore template](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template). It is possible to attach a **external file as template**?

In Backbone View I have:

```
 textTemplate: _.template( $('#practice-text-template').html() ),

 initialize: function(){                                            
  this.words = new WordList;            
  this.index = 0;
  this.render();
 },
```

In my html is:

```
<script id="practice-text-template" type="text/template">
   <h3>something code</h3>
</script>
```

It works well. But **I need external template**.
I try:

```
<script id="practice-text-template" type="text/template" src="templates/tmp.js">
```

or

```
textTemplate: _.template( $('#practice-text-template').load('templates/tmp.js') ),
```

or

```
$('#practice-text-template').load('templates/tmp.js', function(data){ this.textTemplate = _.template( data ) })
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**EDIT: This answer is old and outdated.  I'd delete it, but it is the "accepted" answer.  I'll inject my opinion instead.**

**I wouldn't advocate doing this anymore. Instead, I would separate all templates into individual HTML files.  Some would suggest loading these asynchronously (Require.js or a template cache of sorts).  That works well on small projects but on large projects with lots of templates, you find yourself making a ton of small async requests on page load which I really dislike.  (ugh... ok, you can get around it with Require.js by pre-compiling your initial dependencies with r.js, but for templates, this still feels wrong to me)**

**I like using a grunt task (grunt-contrib-jst) to compile all of the HTML templates into a single templates.js file and include that.  You get the best of all worlds IMO... templates live in a file, compilation of said templates happen at build time (not runtime), and you don't have one hundred tiny async requests when the page starts up.**

**Everything below is junk**

For me, I prefer the simplicity of including a JS file with my template.  So, I might create a file called view_template.js which includes the template as a variable:

```
app.templates.view = " \
    <h3>something code</h3> \
";
```

Then, it is as simple as including the script file like a normal one and then using it in your view:

```
template: _.template(app.templates.view)
```

Taking it a step further, I *actually* use coffeescript, so my code actually looks more like this and avoid the end-of-line escape characters:

```
app.templates.view = '''
    <h3>something code</h3>
'''
```

Using this approach avoids brining in require.js where it really isn't necessary.

Comment: this approach would lose whatever syntax highlighting, reformatting and refactoring functions are available with the ide.  not voting though.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I had to downvote this answer. It's horribly clunky as it'll still keep template files as script files, just kinda forced into looking like templates. Templates need to be templates so if you have to bring in Require.js or use koorchik's brilliant solution below, I feel it's definitely worth it.

Comment: @TommiForsström I agree.  I've moved away from this approach.  Wow!  Dec 4, 2011 is a really long time ago in the world of Backbone.js development :)

Comment: Actually, I'd like to delete this answer but I can't because it is the accepted answer.  It is outdated and there are much better solutions than this.  Today, I would have them as separate template files and use a grunt task (JST, for example) to build them up into a separate templates.js file to avoid the async nature of fetching them all individually.  It is a best of both worlds approach IMO.

Comment: well if there aren't a lot of templates I think the former solution is really the most efficient.

Comment: @silkAdmin Efficient, yes.  Ideal, no.  It works, but I really don't recommend it.  There are lots of negatives to this approach.  And "not a lot of templates" is very rare in any real-world app.  Real-world apps easily have hundreds of templates.

Comment: @BrianGenisio Yeah fair engouth, in probably 90% of cases there will be a lot of templates, but on certain apps I find the former technique very handy. Like everything it's always a matter of weighting pros and cons.

Comment: I am liking this (editted) approach (using JST), except I'm having problems doing this:         `template: JST['test.html']()`, it doesn't seem to be loading the data in from JST :( (see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723392/jst-with-backbone-and-underscore)

Answer (score 107):

Here is a simple solution:

```
var rendered_html = render('mytemplate', {});

function render(tmpl_name, tmpl_data) {
    if ( !render.tmpl_cache ) { 
        render.tmpl_cache = {};
    }

    if ( ! render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] ) {
        var tmpl_dir = '/static/templates';
        var tmpl_url = tmpl_dir + '/' + tmpl_name + '.html';

        var tmpl_string;
        $.ajax({
            url: tmpl_url,
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html', //** Must add 
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                tmpl_string = data;
            }
        });

        render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] = _.template(tmpl_string);
    }

    return render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name](tmpl_data);
}
```

Using "async: false" here is not a bad way because in any case you must wait until template  will be loaded.

So, "render" function

1. allows you to store each template in separate html file in static
   dir
2. is very lightweight
3. compiles and caches templates
4. abstracts template loading logic. For example, in future you can use preloaded and precompiled templates.
5. is easy to use

[I am editing the answer instead of leaving a comment because I believe this to be important.]

if templates are not showing up in ***native app***, and you see `HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERROR: DOM Exception 3`, look at answer by Dave Robinson to [What exactly can cause an "HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3"-Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256394/what-exactly-can-cause-an-hierarchy-request-err-dom-exception-3-error).

Basically, you must add

```
dataType: 'html'
```

to the $.ajax request.

Comment: @BinaryNights - should we always add `dataType: 'html'` to our ajax request, just in case?

Comment: Does this work also for nested views? Apparently I can't have it work if a view refers to another view.

Comment: Yes, it should work for nested templates too. Just add render helper and call it like:  <%= render('nested_template', data) %>

Comment: Hello, may you explain a little bit more about "compiles and caches templates"? When I tried to call the render function it doesn't added the tmpl_data to return value, it just passed it like it is. I had to call "Handlebars.compile" method after that. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

This mixin allows you to render external template using **Underscore** in very simple way: `_.templateFromUrl(url, [data], [settings])`. Method API is almost the same as **Underscore's** [_.template()](http://underscorejs.org/#template). Caching included.

```
_.mixin({templateFromUrl: function (url, data, settings) {
    var templateHtml = "";
    this.cache = this.cache || {};

    if (this.cache[url]) {
        templateHtml = this.cache[url];
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                templateHtml = data;
            }
        });

        this.cache[url] = templateHtml;
    }

    return _.template(templateHtml, data, settings);
}});
```

Usage:

```
var someHtml = _.templateFromUrl("http://example.com/template.html", {"var": "value"});
```

Comment: Really nice little mixin there very neat! :) cheers for sharing

Comment: Very cool D, this was the kind of solution I was looking for. and I think could be used to keep a set of templates private.

Comment: @abhi it is provided in the answer. Also, you need jQuery to load template, but you can rewrite part of code that loads template via AJAX to your taste using any other library.

Comment: @Dmitriy  async: false is  deprecated,so if i call  with out async parameter its is not working,i think this is because by default async is true that means calling syncronisilly,so do you have solution for this issue

Comment: @abhi, it works for jQuery 1.*
Also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11755262/541961

Comment: Great example mixin, thanks. However, may I ask why you use `$.ajax` instead of just calling `$.load(url)` ?

Answer (score 17):

I didn't want to use require.js for this simple task, so I used modified koorchik's solution.

```
function require_template(templateName, cb) {
    var template = $('#template_' + templateName);
    if (template.length === 0) {
        var tmpl_dir = './templates';
        var tmpl_url = tmpl_dir + '/' + templateName + '.tmpl';
        var tmpl_string = '';

        $.ajax({
            url: tmpl_url,
            method: 'GET',
            contentType: 'text',
            complete: function (data, text) {
                tmpl_string = data.responseText;
                $('head').append('<script id="template_' + templateName + '" type="text/template">' + tmpl_string + '<\/script>');
                if (typeof cb === 'function')
                    cb('tmpl_added');
            }
        });
    } else {
        callback('tmpl_already_exists');
    }
}

require_template('a', function(resp) {
    if (resp == 'tmpl_added' || 'tmpl_already_exists') {
        // init your template 'a' rendering
    }
});
require_template('b', function(resp) {
    if (resp == 'tmpl_added' || 'tmpl_already_exists') {
        // init your template 'b' rendering
    }
});
```

Why to append templates to document, rather than storing them in javascript object? Because in production version I would like to generate html file with all templates already included, so I won't need to make any additional ajax requests. And in the same time I won't need to make any refactoring in my code, as I use

```
this.template = _.template($('#template_name').html());
```

in my Backbone views.

Comment: Using this as well, it is great for the scenerio where I trying to use Jasmine for TDD and wish to test templates before I have implemented requirejs and its textjs plugin. Well done @Tramp

Comment: The call to $.ajax is asynchronous, anything depending on the results, should be executed within the done method of the returned promise.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I used it.  One suggestion:  no reason to append as a script tag - could just go ahead and convert to a template and keep it in a look-up hash.  Here's a (non-functional) fiddle example:  http://jsfiddle.net/PyzeF/

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated now

Comment: Since `async: false` is deprecated, I improved the answer, by adding `complete` callback.

Answer (score 16):

This might be slightly off topic, but you could use Grunt (http://gruntjs.com/) - which runs on node.js (http://nodejs.org/, available for all major platforms) to run tasks from the command line. There are a bunch of plugins for this tool, like a template compiler, https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-jst. See documentation on GitHub, https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jst. (You will also need to understand how to run node package manager, https://npmjs.org/. Don't worry, it's incredibly easy and versatile. )

You can then keep all your templates in separate html files, run the tool to precompile them all using underscore (which I believe is a dependency for the JST plugin, but don't worry, node package manager will auto install dependencies for you).

This compiles all your templates to one script, say

```
templates.js
```

Loading the script will set a global - "JST" by default -  which is an array of functions, and can be accessed like so:

`JST['templates/listView.html']()`

which would be similar to

```
_.template( $('#selector-to-your-script-template'))
```

if you put the content of that script tag in (templates/)listView.html

However, the real kicker is this: Grunt comes with this task called 'watch', which will basically monitor changes to files that you have defined in your local grunt.js file (which is basically a config file for your Grunt project, in javascript). If you have grunt start this task for you, by typing:

```
grunt watch
```

from the command line, Grunt will monitor all changes you make to the files and auto-execute all tasks that you have setup for it in that grunt.js file if it detects changes - like the *jst* task described above. Edit and then save your files, and all your templates recompile into one js file, even if they are spread out over a number of directories and subdirectories.

Similar tasks can be configured for linting your javascript, running tests, concatenating and minifying / uglifying your script files. And all can be tied to the watch task so changes to your files will automatically trigger a new 'build' of your project.

It takes some time to set things up and understand how to configure the grunt.js file, but it well, well worth the time invested, and I don't think you will ever go back to a pre-grunt way of working

Comment: Favorite answer.  This should be the accepted answer. (not mine)

Comment: Nice entry point to grunt. It works fine for plain HTML but if I have <%= price%> or similar I get: unexpected token = , failed to compile from grunt

Comment: I am liking this approach (using JST), except I'm having problems doing this:         `template: JST['test.html']()`, it doesn't seem to be loading the data in from JST :( (see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723392/jst-with-backbone-and-underscore)

Answer (score 15):

I think [this](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/) is what might help you. Everything in the solution revolves around `require.js` library which is a JavaScript file and module loader.

The tutorial at the link above shows very nicely how a backbone project could be organized. A [sample implementation](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/tree/gh-pages/examples/modular-backbone) is also provided. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to my site, for anyone looking I have started a project which tries to implement best practises http://backboneboilerplate.com

Answer (score 4):

I got interested on javascript templating and now I'm taking the first steps with backbone. This is what i came up with and seems to work pretty well.

```
window.App = {

    get : function(url) {
        var data = "<h1> failed to load url : " + url + "</h1>";
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: url,
            success: function(response) {
                data = response;
            }
        });
        return data;
    }
}

App.ChromeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template( App.get("tpl/chrome.html") ),
    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
});

App.chromeView = new App.ChromeView({ el : document.body });
App.chromeView.render();
```

Comment: On your `get` function, I'd probably return the `$.ajax` itself so it returns a promise object so in case your template doesn't respond right away.

Answer (score 4):

I had to set the data type to "text" to make it work for me:

```
get : function(url) {
    var data = "<h1> failed to load url : " + url + "</h1>";
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        dataType: "text",
        url: url,
        success: function(response) {
            data = response;
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that works for me with using jQuery.

I add the underscore template code, with jQuery.load() method, to the main html file.

Once it's there, I'm using it for generating the templates. 
All need to happen synchronously!

**The concept is:**

I have a underscore map template code:

```
<!-- MAP TEMPLATE-->
<script type="text/template" id="game-map-template">
    <% _.each(rc, function(rowItem, index){ %>
      <ul class="map-row" data-row="<%- index %>">
        <li class="map-col <%- colItem.areaType ? 'active-area' : '' %>"></li>
        ...
</script>
```

And I put that code in a file called **map-template.html**

After that I create a a wrapper for the template files.

```
<div id="templatesPool"></div>
```

Then I include that file in my main html file like so.

In head:

```
<!-- Template Loader -->
<script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#templatesPool").append($('<div>').load("map-template.html")); 
    });
</script>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is really old but it came up as the first result on a google search for underscore ajax templates.

I was tired of not finding a good solution for this so I created my own:

https://github.com/ziad-saab/underscore-async-templates

In addition to loading underscore templates using AJAX, it adds <% include %> functionality. I hope it can be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit uneasy forcing jQuery to function synchronously, so I modified the previous synchronous example using promises. It's pretty much the same, but runs asynchronously. I'm using hbs templates in this example:

```
var asyncRenderHbs= function(template_name, template_data) {
    if (!asyncRenderHbs.template_cache) { 
        asyncRenderHbs.template_cache= {};
    }

    var promise= undefined;

    if (!asyncRenderHbs.template_cache[template_name]) {
        promise= new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var template_url= '/templates/' + template_name;
            $.ajax({
                url: template_url,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(data) {
                    asyncRenderHbs.template_cache[template_name]= Handlebars.compile(data);
                    resolve(asyncRenderHbs.template_cache[template_name](template_data));
                },
                error: function(err, message) {
                    reject(err);
                }           
            });
        });
    } else {
        promise= Promise.resolve(asyncRenderHbs.template_cache[template_name](template_data));
    }

    return promise;
};
```

Then to use the rendered html:

```
asyncRenderHbs('some_template.hbs', context)
    .then(function(html) {
        applicationMain.append(html);
        // Do other stuff here after html is rendered...
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // Handle errors
    });
```

NOTE: As discussed by others, it would be preferable to compile all templates into a single templates.js file and load that in the beginning rather than have many small synchronous AJAX calls to get templates when the webpage loads.

Answer (score 0):

Forward warning - Here be dragons:

I mention the approach shown below simply to help those struggling to make ASP.NET stacks (and similar frameworks) work harmoniously with the ecosystem of js-libs. It goes without saying that this is not a generic solution. Having said that ...

/endforwardwarning

If you are using ASP.NET you can externalize your templates simply by placing them inside one or more partial views of their own. Aka inside your .cshtml:

```
  @Html.Partial("path/to/template")
```

Inside your template.cshtml:

```
   // this is razorview and thusly if you ever need to use the @ character in here  
   // you will have to either escape it as @@ or use the html codepoint which is &#64
   // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626250/escape-character-in-razor-view-engine
   <script type="text/x-template" id="someId">
        <span class="foo"><%= name %></span>
   </script>
```

And now you can use the template like usual:

```
  _.template($("#someId").html())({ name: "Foobar" });
```

Hope this elusively-obvious approach helps someone save an hour's worth of head-scratching.