# how to put all templates within different HTML file like "AppTmpl.html" and how to access those templates in backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

my application templates are working if they are declared within index.html file.
But, I want to keep all templates in different html file,
like,
-AppTmpl.html

```
<!-- SidebarView Template -->
<script id="sideBarTmpl" type="text/template">
   <div class="inner_div"><img src="images/com_logo.png"></div>
   <div class="inner_div"><img src="images/adv_index.png"></div>
</script> 

<!-- HeaderView Template -->
<script id="folderDivTmpl" type="text/template">
   <div id="div_<%= menu_sequence %>"></div>
</script>
```

I am using underscore templates.
But problem is that these templates are not accessible by underscore.
like,
     this.template = _.template($("#headerTmpl").html(), this.model.toJSON());

So what i need to do like include "AppTmpl.html" file in index.html or something.
Any solutions?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Here's one solution [Require.js](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11979513/972393), here's another [External Template Underscore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366733/external-template-in-underscore) This question is possibly a duplicate.

Comment: @orangewarp there are actually a few others, for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/9834714/384985 and  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8995702/384985. However they all seem to have some issues, for example using a *js* file instead of a `html` file (the difference being that if you use a *js* file you need to escape the end-of-lines, and you lose the syntax highlighting in your IDE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) with the [text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text)

Then you can just load it as you need with requireJS:

```
require(['text!templates/AppTmpl.html'],function(AppTemplate){

     this.template = _.template(AppTemplate);

});
```

Comment: thanx ingro !! But I don't want html files for each template. As i written all templates should be in one html file other than index.html

Comment: Well so I think the best solution would be to create a js file with each template assigned to a different variable, like Tmpl.AppTemplate, Tmpl.GridTemplate etc... This js file has to be included before your App so you can access templates in this way: `this.template = _.template(Tmpl.AppTemplate)` and so on...