# UnderscoreJS nested templates: How do I do it?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, nested

I'm not faced with a technical challenge per se as I have some working code. I'm just not sure this is the right way to go so I'd like to run by some experts before I continue down this path...

I'm using the 'render' function from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10136935/1480182

I then have two Backbone views:

```
DetailLineView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.options = options;
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var variables = { detailLine: this.options.detailLine };
        this.$el.html(render("DetailLine", variables));
    }
});
```

and

```
CustomerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.options = options;
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var dl = "";
        _.each(this.options.customer.attributes.detailLines, function (line) {
            var v = { detailLine: line };
            dl += render("DetailLine", v);
        });

        var variables = { customer: this.options.customer.attributes, detailLinesHtml: dl };
        this.$el.html(render("Customer", variables));
    }
});
```

and of course the corresponding templates.

Now the above code works but as far as I can tell I'm not actually using the DetailLineView.

I have a feeling that there's a (much?) more elegant way of doing this but I fail to see how... can anyone help out?

**EDIT:** A better(?) solution:

I changed my CustomerView to this:

```
CustomerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.options = options;
    },
    render: function () {
        var variables = { customer: this.options.customer.attributes };

        this.$el.html(renderTemplate("Customer", variables));
        var dlv = new DetailLineView({ 
                          el: $('.detailLinesContainer', this.$el), 
                          detailLine: this.options.customer.attributes.detailLines[0] 
                      });
        dlv.render();
    }
});
```

I like it better and I'm now using my DetailLineView...

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my OP with a solution that imho is better than the original.