# Using templates with Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

Helllo, probably this is a common question, but I didn't find the appropriate answer.

I have an html file: header.html which contains a header which I want to display

Here is my Backbone.View

```
el: $(".header"),

initialize: function () {
    this.render();
},

render: function () {
    var template = _.template( $("#header_template").html(), {} );
    this.$el.html( template );
},
```

When I put the code inside a java script template, it works:

```
<script type="text/template" id="header_template">
    code of header.html goes here
</script>
```

But when I use it this way:

```
<script type="text/template" id="about_template" src="header.html"></script>
```

it stops working even though, the firebug sees the code inside a template.

Can someone tell me what my mistake is and how to solve it

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366733/external-template-in-underscore

Comment: so we either put the code in the variable or use get method?

Comment: is there more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to organize your templates is to create a subfolder `tpl`. Here you add all your `.html` files

Coenraets has [a nice tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/backbone-js-lessons-learned-and-improved-sample-app/) where he uses this approach together with a `templateloader` function.

You then load the templates in memory before bootstrapping your backbone application.

```
tpl.loadTemplates(['header', 'wine-details', 'wine-list-item'], function() {
    app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```