# Is it possible to only rerender a part of a template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a template with the divs `#entries` and `#movies` In my `#entries` div I show the models of my movie collection. In my `#movies` div I show the results of a searchquery. (The naming of elements is quite bad, I agree).

In the view which renders the template I have the following events,

```
  events: -> 
    "click li": "addEntry" 
    "click .remove": "destroyEntry" 

  addEntry: (e) -> 
    movie_title = $(e.target).text()
    @collection.create title: movie_title

  appendEntry: (entry) ->
    view = new Movieseat.Views.Entry(model: entry)
    $('#entries').append(view.render().el)

  destroyEntry: (e) -> 
    thisid = @$(e.currentTarget).closest('div').data('id')
    @collection.get(thisid).destroy()
```

The li element gets rendered in the `#movies` div. This way I can click on the results from a different view and add them into a other collection. This works, but there's a problem.

In the same view I have this,

```
  initialize: -> 
    @collection.on('change', @render, this)
    @collection.on('add', @appendEntry, this)
    @collection.on('destroy', @render, this)
    return
```

The problem is that when the collection changes (like when I add or remove a movie from it) it rerenders the template. This means it rerenders the `#entries` and `#movies` div. But now it just renders a empty `#movies` div (without the searchquery collection).

So I was wondering if it's possible to only render a part of a template. In this case I would like to only rerender the `#entries` div and just leave the `#movies` div alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
@collection.on('change', @renderEntries, this)

renderEntries: (entry) ->
    $('#entries').html(render('entries', { entries: yourEntriesCollection.toJSON() }))

//some common.js file

function render(template_name, data)
{
    //here create logic to render specified template by name with data.
    // see example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366733/external-template-in-underscore
    return html;
}
```

you should create template for entries which you can render separately.

Comment: So you're saying when the collection changes do the `renderEntries` function. The `renderEntries` function updates the html of the `#entries` div with the content from the collection. Does the 'render' part in `$('#entries').html(render` refer to the `function render(template_name, data)` ?

Comment: yes, render function is just some utilite you can create to use it anywhere in your app.

Comment: Hm I'm having some trouble understanding `$('#entries').html(render('entries',{entries: yourEntriesCollection.toJSON()}))` I tried it with `$('#entries').html('hello)` which does replace current HTML with `hello`. But I don't understand how to connect this with the template I use to output my data. I have the template in a different folder. Also I don't understand what `{ entries: yourEntriesCollection.toJSON() }` does, or why if I would need it.

Comment: you sad that you need to rerender just your entries. So you need somehow render your entries collection. In proposed solution you need to send your collection (in toJSON() format) to some rendering engine which uses template for entries (which you should create)