# why the load html file from directory in backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

i am trying load file from directory \ in backbone.js but it is not display the text could you please tell where I am doing wrong ?
here is my code
fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/JQu5Q/20/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var ContactManager = new Marionette.Application();
        ContactManager.addRegions({
            mainRegion:"#contend"
        })

        ContactManager.on("start", function(){
            console.log("ContactManager has started!");
            var routers = new R({app: ContactManager})

        });

        ContactManager.start();


    })

function render(tmpl_name, tmpl_data) {
    if ( !render.tmpl_cache ) {
        render.tmpl_cache = {};
    }

    if ( ! render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] ) {
        var tmpl_dir = '/root/template';
        var tmpl_url = tmpl_dir + '/' + tmpl_name + '.html';

        var tmpl_string;
        $.ajax({
            url: tmpl_url,
            method: 'GET',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                tmpl_string = data;
            }
        });

        render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name] = _.template(tmpl_string);
    }

    return render.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name](tmpl_data);
}
```

**Getting error: Uncaught ReferenceError: render is not defined
firstpage.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**
I already defined the function

Comment: don't ever use `async: false` , it blocks all script and the UI

Comment: ok ..can I use async: true..still same issue http://jsfiddle.net/JQu5Q/22/

Comment: well isn't that the default? You can't return data outside of the callbacks though

Comment: I didn't get you ..Actually My aim is to load   a html file which is on directory.Please check my resources .I used firstpage.html router.js firstview.js

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: @charlietfl I take render function from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366733/external-template-in-underscore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69188/discussion-between-pallavi-sharma-and-charlietfl).

Comment: is there any way to load html file