# D3.js: Differences between select("body").selectAll("p") and selectAll("p")?

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js

Does anyone know what is the difference?

My understanding is that both would return the same selections.

However when I am doing an append, if I use selectAll("p") it does not work.

For instance, this works:

```
var foo = d3.select("body")
            .selectAll("p")
            .data([1, 2, 3, 4]);

foo.enter.append("p")
```

While this does does not work:

```
var foo = d3.selectAll("p")
            .data([1, 2, 3, 4]);

foo.enter.append("p")
```

Why is it that the latter doesn't work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short answer here is, "Because there's nothing to append to." While you're correct that `d3.selectAll("p")` and `d3.select("body").selectAll("p")` will select the same *existing* nodes, selecting the `body` element first sets the context for *new* nodes added with the `.append()` method.

Without selecting `body`, you have no point in the DOM tree to insert your nodes - I'm guessing that d3 attempts to append the new nodes to the `document` object, which results in the `HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERROR` [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256394/what-exactly-can-cause-an-hierarchy-request-err-dom-exception-3-error).