# Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, domexception

I'm trying to develop an app for Google Chrome: [Packaged Apps](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/apps.html)

In my apolicação, use the command `$.get` to retrieve an HTML page and insert it into the current page:

**Page HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap"></div>
</body>
```

**Script**

```
$.get(url, function(html) {
    $("#wrap").html(html);
});
```

The error occurs on the line: `$("#wrap").html(html);`

### Attempts

Searching the internet, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256394/what-exactly-can-cause-an-hierarchy-request-err-dom-exception-3-error) here on stackoverflow, but this did not help me much.

Another detail is that this example is not a Chrome Web App.
This same example, works perfectly posted on the Internet at: http://ridermansb.kodingen.com/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your response is HTML, try specifying the `dataType` in the `$.get()` like so:

```
$.get(url, function(html) {
    $("#wrap").html(html);
}, 'html');
```

I just had exactly the same problem attaching the response from a jQuery `$.post()`. The response is HTML but jQuery could not (for whatever reason) correctly determine the data type.

Comment: If you control the html, you might also have success inserting <!doctype html> at the top if it is missing.  (Worked for me in a Safari extension.)