# jQuery: Remove element TITLE attribute temporarily on HOVER

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, syntax-error, title

I created tooltips to substitute the default browser "TITLE" bubble. I've read a lot of threads and all of them suggests I should remove `title` temporarily on `mouseover` and put it back on later. I am trying to do exacly that, but I am failing to. Here is my code and the reason why I use jQuery `live` is because I want the effect to apply to dynamically added elements later:

```
tooltip : {
    activate : function(selector){
        $(selector).each(function(){
            $(selector).live('mouseover',function(e){
                tooltip.init(this,true,e);
            });
            $(selector).live('mouseout',function(e){
            tooltip.init(this,false,e);
            });
        });
    },
    init : function(elem,show,e){
        var title = $(elem).attr('title');
        this.addTip(elem,show,title);

        ...
    },
    addTip : function(elem,show,title) {
        var code = '<div class="tooltip-wrapper">'+title+'</div>';
        if(show) {
            $(elem).after(code);
            setTimeout('$(".tooltip-wrapper").fadeIn("slow")',500);
        }
        else {
            $(".tooltip-wrapper").remove();
        }
    }
}
```

I call this script like this:

```
tooltip.activate(selector);
```

Another problem I have is that it gives me `HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3` error if I try this `tooltip.activate("*");`, but it works if I use `input` as a selector.

Any input will be much appreciated :-)

Comment: You're trying to append something to `document`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256394/what-exactly-can-cause-an-hierarchy-request-err-dom-exception-3-error

Comment: You are refering to the `HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3` error? I'll correct that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just point to a couple issues:

- Using `live` inside `each` defeats the idea of `live`. `each` loops over existing elements, not future elements.
- But in any case, the way you're doing it is wrong. You should drop the `each` (in `activate`), because `live` already applies to multiple elements. So in your case, if you have N elements, you'll be adding the same event listener N times.
- `*` applies to all the elements, which could be very inefficient. How about trying `[title]` (applies to elements that have a `title` attribute)
- If you remove the title temporarily on hover, then the title is meaningless (because it only appears on hover). If you're creating an improved tooltip based on the title attribute just read the title attribute when you first encounter it and use it for your tooltip
- You should probably use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`. If an element with a title has child elements you want the tooltip to keep showing when the mouse goes in/out child elements.

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this?

```
addTip : function(elem,show,title) {
        var code = '<div class="tooltip-wrapper">'+title+'</div>';
        if(show) {

            $(elem).after(code);
            $(elem).removeAttr('title');
            setTimeout('$(".tooltip-wrapper").fadeIn("slow")',500);
        }
        else {
            $(".tooltip-wrapper").remove();
            $(elem).attr('title',title);
        }
    }
```

Comment: that seems imposible, are we sure elem is the right selector?