# Javascript and IE error HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

So I am reworking an old project I did. It worked fine in Chrome but in IE it doesn't work so well. It basically dynamically creates selects, then on the final one spits out the choices selected and a somewhat humorous response. But in IE it freaks out and throws me a "SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3) " does anybody know what is wrong with it? Any help is appreciated.

here is the site http://goo.gl/WcSqJ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly can cause an “HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3”-Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1256394/843985).

Answer (score 0):

**HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR code 3**

This node is not allowed to have children of the new node's type, or the new node is already an ancestor of this node; for example, attempting to append an Element node to a Text node.
For more information visit [this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/DOMException#DOMException__HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR).

Comment: Ok. So whats the best way to fix it?

Comment: Can you please post some relevant code that are being used to generate your dynamic element.

Comment: pEle.appendChild(xmlDocTemp.getElementsByTagName('answer')[id.charAt(i)].childNodes[0]); is the line im getting the issue at

Comment: This is not enough to find out the problem but what I can see now is that, getElementsByTagName('answer') is not correct because answer is not a valid html tag, it should be using a valid html tag like "div", "p" e.t.c. and what is charAt(i), looks like a loop's counter, if possible please post more code, so I can see what and how pEle and other objects are connected to each other.

Comment: Is this being generated from an xml file ?

Comment: I think it's ( getElementsByTagName('answer') ) ok if it's being generated from an xml file.

Comment: yea. thats why i was linking to the page itself. There is a few xml files that i pull things from and 'answer' is one of those tags

Comment: Which version of ie displays the errors ? I've found 5 errors till now in your script.

Comment: so far ive only been able to test 9

Comment: Can you replace your appendChild methods with innerHtml=someitem; it could solve your problem, hopefully.