# writing to child window in IE9 with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Im tryin to write to a child window using jQuery and IE9.  Below is the JS with jQuery 1.7.1 code I am using:

```
    var w = window.open();  

    sQuery("head", w.document).append(sQuery("<link/>").attr("rel", "stylesheet").attr("href", "css/inlinecss.css"));

    sQuery("body", w.document).append(sQuery("<div/>").addClass("smdisplaychat").append(sQuery(".smdisplaychat").html()));
```

This code works perfect in Chrome, half way in FireFox (its losing some CSS for some reason, but that is probably a different issue), but in IE9 I get nothing but this error:

```
DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3)
```

In IE9, it throws the exception when trying both statements.  Looked up the [error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg592979%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN, and its pretty generic, anybody know why I cant insert the HTML there?

Comment: Try doing this without jQuery (i.e. `createElement`)

Comment: Check related issues here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256394/what-exactly-can-cause-an-hierarchy-request-err-dom-exception-3-error

Comment: same error when using plain ol' javascript.

Comment: i was wrong, i wrote the wrong js.  adding answer

Answer (score 1):

I used document.write and it seems to have worked, although it doesnt look as pretty.  Below is what i changed my JS to:

```
  var w = window.open();

w.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>" +
    "<link rel='stylesheet' href = 'css/inlinecss.css' />" +
    "</head><body>" + sQuery("<div/>").addClass("smdisplaychat").append(sQuery(".smdisplaychat").html()).html() +
    "</body></html>");
```

on a side, note, it also seems to have eliminated the FF css issue I mentioned in my OP.