# moving google maps v3 around

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to dynamically move a google map (v3) from one div to the other and the first time I move the map from div "x" to "y" the map jumps nicely, but when I try to move it back to "x", I get:

Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3

I've tried using:

```
var mapNode1 = map.getDiv();
$("#miniMap").append(mapNode1);
```

to jump from largeMap to miniMap

and vice versa by using:

```
var mapNode2 = map.getDiv();
$("#largeMap").append(mapNode2);
```

I've also tried using:

```
$("#largeMap").appendTo("#miniMap");
```

and
    $("#miniMap").appendTo("#largeMap");

With both methods, I am getting:
    Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using  #largeMap as element for the Map-initialization? If yes this cannot work, because getDiv() in that case will return #largeMap, and you cannot append  #largeMap to #largeMap(it's the same element)

Comment: ah yes, you're right. that's why it wasn't working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrmm, turns out the following worked:

I put miniMap inside a miniMapWrapper div and largeMap inside largeMapWrapper and used:

```
var mapNode1 = map.getDiv();
$("#miniMap").append(mapNode1);
```

and

```
$("#largeMap").appendTo("#largeMapWrapper");
```

to go back

Answer (score 1):

The most probable causes for the error you describe are listed in [another post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256394/what-exactly-can-cause-an-hierarchy-request-err-dom-exception-3-error). See the accepted answer there. Otherwise, I have to see more of your code (maybe the full source) to try to find the exact cause of the error.