# jqueryUI Sortable: Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, domexception

I've been using this tutorial to build a page where we can reorder and move div on a page:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/

I've modified it to be able to dynamically add some divs on the page but when trying to reorder/move some of the divs, I sometimes get this error: Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3.

Here's my html:

```
<div id="columns">
<ul id="column1" class="column">
</ul>
<ul id="column2" class="column">
</ul>
<ul id="column3" class="column">
</ul>
<ul id="column4" class="column">
</ul>
```

​

And here's the js:

```
$('.column').sortable({
    items: $('li', '.column'),
    connectWith: '.column',
    handle: '.widget-head',
    placeholder: 'widget-placeholder',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    containment: 'document',
    start: function(e, ui) {
        $(ui.helper).addClass('dragging');
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(ui.item).css({
            width: ''
        }).removeClass('dragging');
        $('.column').sortable('enable');
    }
    });


$('#addAWidget').on('click', function(event) {
    var newWidget = '<li class="widget color-white"><div class="widget-head"><h3>Newly         added widget</h3></div><div class="widget-content"><p>Yet another lorem ipsum !</p></div>    </li>';
    $(newWidget).appendTo('#column' + $('#columnNumber').val()).sortable({
        items: $('> li', '.column'),
        connectWith: '.column',
        handle: '.widget-head',
        placeholder: 'widget-placeholder',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        containment: 'document',
        start: function(e, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).addClass('dragging');
        },
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            $(ui.item).css({
                width: ''
           }).removeClass('dragging');
            $('.column').sortable('enable');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's my (simplified) code: http://jsfiddle.net/XnEwg/5/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256394/what-exactly-can-cause-an-hierarchy-request-err-dom-exception-3-error may be this could help.

Comment: Thx Daniel, I already read this post and from what I understand, I'm trying to drag and drop a div into a bad place in the DOM, but I don't know how to change that with the options of sortable. Does it have to do with "containment" or "placeholder" ? I'm certain I'm doing something wrong with sortable, but I can't see what :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sortable should only be initialized once on container of items, you don't need do do anything when you add new items. Also `items` option should be string (selector) not an array of elements. Here is a simplified working version of your code:

```
$('.column').sortable({
    items: '> li',
    connectWith: '.column',
    handle: '.widget-head',
    placeholder: 'widget-placeholder',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    revert: 300,
    delay: 100,
    opacity: 0.8,
    containment: 'document',
    start: function(e, ui) {
        $(ui.helper).addClass('dragging');
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(ui.item).css({
            width: ''
        }).removeClass('dragging');
    }
});

$('#addAWidget').on('click', function(event) {
    var newWidget = '<li class="widget color-white"><div class="widget-head"><h3>Newly added widget</h3></div><div class="widget-content"><p>Yet another lorem ipsum !</p></div></li>';
    $(newWidget).appendTo('#column' + $('#columnNumber').val());
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHrBw/)