# DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3) error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, domexception

The following code works fine in chrome and Firefox, but breaks in IE 9.0.

> `message.nodeTree.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].appendChild(pkf_util.createXmlTextNode(text));`

when I try to input something via textarea,it comes with SCRIPT5022:

> DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3) line 481 character 29;

Any ideas why it's not working in IE 9.0?

Comment: There's no telling without seeing your HTML structure, but the code _does_ look very fragile.

Comment: Since you've tagged jQuery, you should use it as well, and not navigate "second child's first child's first child" style but rather "an input with class `.data` within the div that was clicked" style

Comment: What is suppose to return function createXmlTextNode()  ?

Comment: "Dom exception 3" means you're trying to append something where it doesn't belong, such as appending something that isn't an HTML node to an HTML document.

Comment: see also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256394/what-exactly-can-cause-an-hierarchy-request-err-dom-exception-3-error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know its a long time since the Q was asked but I reached it based on the error message.
specifically in my case I was getting the following error: "HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3: A Node was inserted somewhere it doesn't belong.".

I was trying to append a node that I was creating using jquery to some other node in my html document.
It turned out that by mistake I used `$('div')` instead of `$('<div>')` for the creating the new (appended) node.

I hope this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`DOM exception 3` means you've tried to insert an element to a place in the DOM where it doesn't belong.
([ref.](HTTP://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMException))

Possible causes:

- IE9 doesn't consider the XML node created by the library a valid DOM node.
- The node created is a valid DOM node but it's being appended somewhere it doesn't belong (such as anything being appended to a node that's supposed to be a leaf)
- The node created is not actually a new element, but rather a parent of the node being appended to. This would classify as a bug in the library.
- If you try to append a `null` anywhere, you're practically asking for a DOM exception. Perhaps your library fails on IE9?

Google search on `pkf_util` returns ... this question, so we cannot rule out a bug in `pkf_util`.

Comment: Not sure how that happened... provided a new one.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution...

```
var element = document.createElement('iframe');
element.src = url;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(element);
```

Good luck