# Twitter bootstrap - show modal by clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sinatra

I'm using twitter bootstrap. I want modal to be shown by clicking on a link **using javascript**.

```
$("#my-link-id").click($(this).modal());
```

However, the code above causes an error of

```
Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are calling the method `modal` before the user click's `#my-link-id`, the fix:

```
$("#my-link-id").click(function() {
    $(this).modal();
});
```

or:

```
$("#my-link-id").on("click", function() {
    $(this).modal();
});
```

---

To see an explanation on the error you can read here: [What exactly can cause an "HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3"-Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256394/what-exactly-can-cause-an-hierarchy-request-err-dom-exception-3-error)

Answer (score 2):

need to do preventDefault on the event to stop the click following the link instead of opening the modal.

```
    $("#my-link-id").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).modal();
    });
```