# d3js load static svg not working in IE9 (responseXML = null)

Tags: javascript, xml, d3.js, internet-explorer-9

The following D3JS example is not working in IE9 and it seems like its caused by how IE9 parses the XML? Any idea on how to get the example working in IE9 is MUCH appriciated!

Demo: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1014829

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

So, after looking into your issue using the IE9 Developer Tools (F12 key), you are getting a `DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3)` error on the `document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);` JavaScript call. There is another issue I found on StackOverflow that is in regards to this issue: [What exactly can cause an "HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3"-Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256394/what-exactly-can-cause-an-hierarchy-request-err-dom-exception-3-error)

Have you confirmed that you are getting back the correct data when you make the call to the `rect01.svg` file? If so, then I would spend some time with the IE Developer Tools and see what you can come up with.

Good luck!