# HierarchyRequestError - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of data that I want to append to an existing table. So, I am basically adding rows to a table by cloning the last row.

```
1) var clonedRow = $("#tableId" tr:last-child").clone(true);
```

While looping through the array of data, I set new values for each columns in the clonedRow

```
2)
  $("td", clonedRow).eq(1).html("new data"); 
  $("td", clonedRow).eq(2).html("new data");
```

and append to the table.

```
3) $"#tableId").append(clonedRow);
```

The loop continues (cloning, inserting values, appending...).

I thought it might be faster if I append outside of the loop, so I created a documentFragment

```
4) var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
```

and appended clonedRow to the fragment instead of the table

```
5) docFrag.appendChild(clonedRow);
```

And then when it was all completed, I would append the document fragment to the table:

```
6) $("#"+gridID).appendChild(frag);
```

The problem is that I am getting **HierarchyRequestError** right where I am appending the row to the document fragment (step 5).  Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when insertion of an element to a specific point in the DOM is not allowed or you are trying to move a node into itself. And there are plenty of other reason for same.

**[Refer answer by kelly norton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1258409/1719752)**

Comment: I read through the link, but I am still unsure how to resolve my problem. So I can't append a cloned row into a document fragment?

Comment: You should rather put the elements into a jQuery object, and then clone() that rather than using `createDocumentFragment`

Comment: guess im just confused on what you mean by putting elements in a jQuery object.  I am using the example from http://learn.jquery.com/performance/append-outside-loop/