# Input inside Jquery UI Dialog not being sent?

Tags: html, forms, jquery-ui, post

The input fields in my dialog box aren't being posted, and i'm not sure why...

i've tested it on mac firefox and safari, and windows IE & firefox with the same results, so i don't think it's the browser, and the fields post fine if I disable the dialog box.

I've re-read the jquery ui docs and can't find what i'm doing wrong... It seems unlikely that the dialog box wouldn't support input.

here's a condensed version of the code i'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dialog").dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   buttons: {
    "OK": function() {
     $(this).dialog('close');
    }
   }
  });
  $("#publishSettings").click(function(){
   $("#dialog").dialog('open');
  });
 });
</script>

<form method="POST" action="publish.php">
 <input type="button" id="publishSettings" value="Publish Settings">
 <div id="dialog">
  Publish Date
  <input type="text" name="publishOn"><br>
  Unpublish Date
  <input type="text" name="unPublishOn">
 </div>
 <input type="submit" name="pubArticle" value="Publish">
</form>
```

Nothing out of the ordinary, right? Why won't this work for me!?

thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When JQuery opens the dialog box , it moves it outside the form.

Here's the solution for that:

[jQuery UI Dialog with ASP.NET button postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757232/jquery-ui-dialog-with-asp-net-button-postback)

basically in your case:

```
var dlg =  $("#dialog").dialog({ 
   autoOpen: false, 
   buttons: { 
    "OK": function() { 
     $(this).dialog('close'); 
    } 
   } 
  }); 
dlg.parent().appendTo($("#yourformId"));
```

should fix it.

Comment: Tricky! I saw that question, but didn't finish reading it because i thought it was asp.net specific. whoops. 

Thanks!!

Comment: Since jQuery UI v1.10.0 you can do this directly using the appendTo property - http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo

Comment: This is dumb. Jquery is supposed to make it easier. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Problem with appendTo is if your dialog is meant to be hidden most of the time .. the input fields within the dialog appear at the bottom of the form even if the dialog isn't open. I got around this by adding $(this).appendTo($('#$strHostForm')); to the dialog close button handler, rather than putting it in the definition - my close handler then posts the form, so the user doesn't see the fields appear

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone who have the same issue there is a newer and simpler solution: an "appendTo" option has been introduced in jQuery UI 1.10.0

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    appendTo: "form"
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure jQuery UI breaks out the Dialog section from its normal place in the dom and then moves it to a different place. That would take your input element out of the form parent element. You can't submit a form without a form element, so that's why it fails.

I would suggest rewriting the html as:

```
<div id="dialog">
<form method="POST" action="publish.php">
 <input type="button" id="publishSettings" value="Publish Settings">
  Publish Date
  <input type="text" name="publishOn"><br>
  Unpublish Date
  <input type="text" name="unPublishOn">
 <input type="submit" name="pubArticle" value="Publish">
</form>
</div>
```

If the publishSettings button needs to not be in the popup, then you could move it out of the form and just capture its value on the submit event and add it as a hidden input element before anything gets submitted.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

On html5 compliant browsers (not IE, but latest ff, chrome and safari support it), you can set the "form" attribute on your input fields, and doing so lets you place them wherever you want. I suffered this problem too and took some time to figure out why ie did not send dialog inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the solution was (like user2100025 said) to add the "appendTo = '#yourform'," in your code. Here my code and it's working fine.

I hope it helo someone :)

```js
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      resizable: false,
      modal: true,
      appendTo: '#myform',
      buttons: {
        "Yes"function() {
            $( '#myform' ).submit();
        },
        'No' function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    });

    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
  </script>
```