# Problems in posting value from Jquery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery

I have submit button in side the jquery ui dialog and the dialog is inside a form. I am posting values to the same or different php page. But what I found that the values are not posted and actually submit button is not working at all. What is the fix? Please help with your opinions.

thanks

Comment: You should post your HTML and JavaScript

Comment: var mydlg = $("#brandwindow").dialog({ width: 800, height: 350, title: 'Edit a Brand' });
            mydlg.parent().appendTo("form:first");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: Actually, I think this is the answer:**
[Input inside Jquery UI Dialog not being sent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611687/input-inside-jquery-ui-dialog-not-being-sent)

I know this is old, but just ran into the issue myself.

It seems that form elements that are set to display:none, are not posted to the server side.

I create a text dialog, with an input in it, I set a value for it.
I then created an input just outside of my dialog div, and set another value.

When posting the form, I get a null for the first, and the proper value for the second...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `form` items have their `name` attributes set and that your submit button is an `input` with type of `submit`.  Also, `form` elements cannot be nested, so ensure you aren't doing that.

Comment: I just tested with what you said, but I found them not working and posting is not successful. What may be issue with jqueryui and posting values?

Comment: It's hard to know why your code isn't working without seeing your code.  As far as I know, jQuery shouldn't prevent an HTML form from being posted, so there must be something else in your code that's incorrect.