# How to get textbox value from jQuery modal dialog after postback?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, dialog, postback

How do I get the ASP.NET text boxes updated with the value of the entered form data?
The code below is basically the [modal dialog form sample from jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form), but with ASP.NET text boxes.
The post back is fired, however the text box is not updated.

After post back, I don't have the values in my test boxes. I'm pretty sure this is an easy one, but my brain is blocked now, and can't figure out why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="Styles/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
        body { font-size: 62.5%; }
        label, input { display:block; }
        input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
        fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
        h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
        div#users-contain {  width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
        div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
        div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
        .ui-button { outline: 0; margin:0; padding: .4em 1em .5em; text-decoration:none;  !important; cursor:pointer; position: relative; text-align: center; }
        .ui-dialog .ui-state-highlight, .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em;  }


    </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

      var name = $("#name"),
            email = $("#email"),
            password = $("#password"),
            allFields = $([]).add(name).add(email).add(password),
            tips = $("#validateTips");

      function updateTips(t) {
        tips.text(t).effect("highlight", {}, 1500);
      }

      function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {

        if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
          o.addClass('ui-state-error');
          updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + ".");
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }

      function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
        if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {
          o.addClass('ui-state-error');
          updateTips(n);
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }

      $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        open: function(type,data){
          $('#dialog').parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
        },
        buttons: {
          'Create an account': function () {

            var bValid = true;
            allFields.removeClass('ui-state-error');

            bValid = bValid && checkLength(name, "username", 3, 16);
            bValid = bValid && checkLength(email, "email", 6, 80);
            bValid = bValid && checkLength(password, "password", 5, 16);
            bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter.");
            bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com");
            bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9");

            if (bValid) {
              $('#users tbody').append('<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + name.val() + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + email.val() + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + password.val() + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>');
              $(this).dialog('close');
              <%=this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(this.Button1))%>;
            }
          },
          Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
          }
        },
        close: function () {
          allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
        }
      });

      $('#createuser1').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
      })

        .hover(
            function () {
              $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
            },
            function () {
              $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
            }
        ).mousedown(function () {
          $(this).addClass("ui-state-active");
        })
        .mouseup(function () {
          $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active");
        });

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="javascript: $('#dialog').dialog('open');return false;"
      OnClick="Button1_Click" />
  </div>
  <div class="demo">
    <div id="dialog" title="Create new user">
      <p id="validateTips">
        All form fields are required.</p>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="name">
          Name</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" name="name" ID="name" CssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">UserUser</asp:TextBox>
        <label for="email">
          Email</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" name="email" ID="email" CssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">test@test.com</asp:TextBox>
        <label for="password">
          Password</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" name="password" ID="password" CssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">password</asp:TextBox>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
    <h1>
      Existing Users:</h1>
    <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
      <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
          <th>
            Name
          </th>
          <th>
            Email
          </th>
          <th>
            Password
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            John Doe
          </td>
          <td>
            john.doe@example.com
          </td>
          <td>
            johndoe1
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string name = this.name.Text;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757232/jquery-ui-dialog-with-asp-net-button-postback).

Comment: The post back is actually firing, so it's a different issue. I have the "form fix" already in place in my open function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dialog.close` function is clearing all the fields before the page posts:

```
close: function () {
    allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
}
```

You should probably move the call to `val('')` into `dialog.open` (if that still provides the intended user experience).

Comment: Great. That was the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Also can save in hidden fields

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking in consideration that ASP.NET changes the actual ID of all "Server" controls when it generates the HTML sent to the browser?  I'm assuming that you are talking about a full page postback, not doing some Ajax postback - I hope you find this helpful.

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtTestBox" name="txtTestBox" runat="server">  
Test Value</asp:TextBox>
```

turns into (I'm showing the values of id/name as an example, you'll have to look at the HTML source to see what value ASP.NET is generating):

```
<input type="text" id="ctl00_PlaceHolder1_txtTextBox"  
name="ctl00$PlaceHolder1$txtTestBox" value="Test Value" />
```

There is a snippit of jQuery that helps deal with selecting ASP.NET controls:

```
function $$(id, context) {
    var el = $("#" + id, context);
    if (el.length < 1)
        el = $("[id$=_" + id + "]", context);
    return el;
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
var testValue = $$('txtTestBox').val();
```

This little javascript will search through the DOM elements to find a control that ends with 'txtTestBox', which should help you grab the ASP.NET element by the name you gave it when you defined the element in the aspx file.  Keep in mind that this is not as performant as $('#whateverId'), but the IDs generated by ASP.NET are not guaranteed to stay the same (i.e. if you change the name of a placeholder, content area, master page stuff - it can change the ID of the control).

As a note, ASP.NET 4.0 will have extra properties on server controls that allow you to define the actual ID of a HTML element instead of ASP.NET deciding what to call a control.