# Retrieving value of a textbox that is inside a fancyBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Using the latest version of fancyBox via inline mode, and I'm unable to get the value of a textbox to submit data.

Using a regular input button, not an asp.net control, but the textbox is asp.net.

```
document.getElementById('<%= txtCancelReason.ClientID %>');
```

That works when I initialize the fancyBox, but if I click the submit button, the value is empty. Have tried using jQuery to get the value, nothing works.

Thoughts?

Comment: This is an ASP.NET issue and is answered in this question:
[Fancybox ASP.NET button not working][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686362/fancybox-asp-net-button-not-working

Answer (score 0):

can you see the HTML code generated for the textbox? you can use Jquery to get a reference to the control that the ID is ending with txtCancelReason

```
$('input:text[id$=\'txtCancelReason\']').val();
```

will give you the value of the textbox

Comment: I tried this, and also with the clientID and they both return undefined. Something is up with fancyBox causing this, just not sure what the heck it is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried targeting the a Fancybox class and then searching in it for your textbox?

```
$('#button-id').on('click', function () {
    var $textbox = $('.fancybox-wrap').find('input[type="text"]'),
        textVal  = $textbox.val();
});
```

Both Fancy box 1.x.x and 2.x.x use the `.fancybox-wrap` class so it should work in either version.

You can also select the text-box relatively to your button:

```
$('#button-id').on('click', function () {
    var $textbox = $(this).closest('form').find('input[type="text"]'),
        textVal  = $textbox.val();
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.bind()`.

Comment: And I tried this too, but it won't bind in the fancybox for me. Maybe I need to do all of this outside the box.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with the fact that I'm opening the fancybox from a function and not a click even with an anchor tag?

Comment: Is your `inline` content being pulled in through AJAX or in an IFRAME?

Comment: I have it defined as inline for the fancybox and it happens to be a user control that is on the parent page and inside a div.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

1. Inspect your page and get the id of the form let's say : **form1**
2. Search fancybox js file for : **appendTo("body")** and replace it with **appendTo("#form1")**

and it will work like a charm