# fancyBox not displaying properly

Tags: jquery, fancybox, colorbox, anythingslider

I've attempted to implement fancyBox to the page listed below, however, the lightbox is not being generated onClick.

I'm properly calling and generating the fancyBox in the example below, but it does not seem to initiate when the anchor element is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/jodriscoll/Xf7qf/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".fancyBox").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

As you can see, I am calling a condensed version of fancyBox and all the proper CSS styling/class associations are properly built.

If I missed something, please tell me where then politely call me an idiot :)

Thanks!

Comment: Quick note, the last two slides of the slideshow I'm using this within are the ones that will be initiating the fancyBox (#&panel-10 / #&panel1-11).

Comment: It's working for me in chrome

Comment: Got a javascript error. Did you do a find and replace of $ with jquery? this line slider.jQuerycontrols.find('img').tooltip(); was giving an error. I changed it to slider.$controls.find('img') and no error. launching video on another url through an iframe in jsfiddle won't work. See if fixing that line solves your issue. Another javascript error, is that there is no tooltip.

Comment: I just attempted to fix that $/jQuery issue and it still doesn't work.  It should function properly in jsFiddle, it's one of the main domains that is used to demonstrate the plugin.

Comment: ^ See, it functions fine inside of jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xW5gs/

Comment: It appears when I reference the jquery.fancybox.pack.js version, the fancyBox does not initiate. However, if I reference the jquery.fancybox.js version, it initiates perfectly fine...

Comment: `when I reference the jquery.fancybox.pack.js version, the fancyBox does not initiate` : you may need to check your paths (or use an absolute path instead)

Comment: BTW : are you really using colorbox ? (fancybox and colorbox are two different plugins)

Comment: JFK, I'm only using fancyBox at the moment.

Comment: I managed to get it to fucntion, however, fancyBox is not working in IE8. Any idea why this is happening?

http://www.massgeneral.org/international/dev/full-screen.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open file 'jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js' and replace word "body" to "form". There are two words "body" there.
Thanks to tuyenbui.

And the problem is also solved in this page : [Fancybox - ASP.NET button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686362/fancybox-asp-net-button-not-working/4067885)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! However, I no longer work for this client, but I will pass this information along.

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't work in IE8 because you have a comma at the end of the thumbs array. IE8+ is strict and doesn't like trailing commas.