# How to call a callback function in a fancybox div using c# and code-behind?

Tags: c#, jquery, callback, fancybox, code-behind

I have added fancybox v.2.1.5 in my webpage just like follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
```

This is my html code:

```
<form id="aspnetForm" runat="server">
    <a href="#fancyBoxDiv" class="fancybox" />//When the anchor is clicked, shows fancyBoxDiv
    <div id="fancyBoxDiv">//This div is shown in fancybox
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my c# code-behind:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This function is never called
}
```

And I have one c# button on one fancybox div, but when I press this button, the callback function in codebehind is not called.
What I'm doiing wrong? What I have to change?

Comment: Can you give more details about your coding stack?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put your `asp:Button` element inside a `form` tag like below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <a href="#fancyBoxDiv" class="fancybox" />//When the anchor is clicked, shows fancyBoxDiv
    <div id="fancyBoxDiv">//This div is shown in fancybox
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: PLease, look at my question now. I've added code and it's still not working. Best regards.

Comment: Does the button work when you put it out of the fancybox?

Comment: I did not check it very well but the link seems to be similar to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686362/fancybox-asp-net-button-not-working

Comment: I saw this link before to post my question, but the code in the link is for a previous version of Fancybox, so I don't have this code as is shown in the post in my version (v.2.1.5)

Answer (score 0):

If you think your html structure is proper then you can check if you're getting any exception on client side in firebug. Or second option will be to check if you're able to call a client side function by using `OnClientClick`. If so then call the client side function and use `_doPostBack`.