# How we will open a popup or shadow box on button within one page click in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem with open a popup or shadow box . i Want to that when we are run xyz page and on that page when we click on add button the popup or shadow box will be open. 
plz suggest me.

"Thanks"

Comment: C# does not have any pop-ups. "You're Welcome"

Answer (score 0):

Popups are done by toggling visibility of a dom element. This task cannot be directly accomplished with c#.  I'd suggest googling 'how to make a popup' and see the very simple html + javascript examples. Jquery also would be a library for making this task even easier.

Answer (score 0):

If using ajaxcontroltoolkit you can use ModalPopup.show .If not you can use jquery modal

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting the popup to show onbutton click event?
If you are using a jquery or a javascript call the function using the "onClientClick"  attribute of the button control.
In case of AJAX use modappopup's show() function
Eg : modalpopupname.Show()

Answer (score 0):

That can be best achieved using Jquery Modals. Refer [JQuery Modals](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)

If you intend to user postback from the Jquery UI dialog one problem you would come accross that jquery moves the dialog outside of the Form tags. To solve this problem you need to move it back inside the form tags :

```
   jQuery(function() {
    var dlg = jQuery("#dialog").dialog({ 
                    draggable: true, 
                    resizable: true, 
                    show: 'Transfer', 
                    hide: 'Transfer', 
                    width: 320, 
                    autoOpen: false, 
                    minHeight: 10, 
                    minwidth: 10 
     });
      dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
});
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757232/jquery-ui-dialog-with-asp-net-button-postback) SO Post for more information on the above issue.