# Open aspx page in modal popup

Tags: asp.net, popup, modal-dialog

I have an aspx page (let say page1.aspx) having labels and buttons on it. In some other page i need to show content of page1.aspx in modal popup. I have read many articles, but did't find exact solution. Some of the possible ideas are, 1: create Usercontrol, 2: Use Server.execute() method.

Please suggest any solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to show a popup (a modal dialog) you can create an user control which contains the markup form page1.aspx and use either [AjaxControlTookit (ModalPopup)](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) or [jQuery.dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog)

I prefer the jQuery.Dialog, it saves 2 postbacks to the server and is easier to integrate.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/768163/782754) is how to integrate it with ASP .Net, a little trick so the inputs inside that dialog will be posted to server, when the button is clicked.