# Asp button not working in a jquery dialog box

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, button, dialog

Asp button is not working in a jquery dialog box:

```
<script type="txt/js">$(function () {$('#<%= ButtonEmail.UniqueID %>').button();});</script>

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Cadastro">
<p>Digite seu email para que eviemos o link do cadastro para ele:</p>
<p><asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmail" CssClass="ui-corner-all" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="ButtonEmail" runat="server" Text="Enviar Link" onclick="ButtonEmail_Click" /></p>
<div><asp:Label ID="LabelEmail" runat="server" Text="teste"></asp:Label></div>
</div>
```

c# code:

```
protected void ButtonEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
}
```

even when a delete this: $(function () {$('#<%= ButtonEmail.UniqueID %>').button();}); dont work, the button stays with the original design, but dont work

Comment: I think the .button function isn't working.  It's supposed to provide visual enhancement to the input.  Jquery UI I believe.  However the OP really should let us know ;).

Comment: please take a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757232/jquery-ui-dialog-with-asp-net-button-postback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
          $('#<%= ButtonEmail.ClientID %>').button();
     });
</script>
```

Please note the ClientID which replaced UniqueId.  Also ensure that the dependent scripts are loaded (There should be no javascript errors).

After reading some of the comments on the other answer, I'm starting to wonder if possibly it's your server side click event which is not working?  In that case you're probably going to have to provide more information  and code.

To make an asp.net server side click work in a dialog, ensure that the dialog is part of the form (after its been made into a dialog by jquery.  Details are here.  [jQuery UI Dialog with ASP.NET button postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757232/jquery-ui-dialog-with-asp-net-button-postback)

Answer (score 0):

may be something like this

var buttonId = <%= ButtonEmail.UniqueID %>;
$(function () {$('#' + buttonId).button();});

Comment: you're storing the control id into `buttonId`, but when you try to use it, you're using a string and not the variable that you created... fail

Comment: yea true may be  $(function () {$('#' + buttonId).button();});

Comment: removed my -1 vote, but that's not the issue tho. This translates to the exact same thing the OP is doing, but nobody knows what the problem *really* is

Comment: I know but just trying to give an idea how something like that could be achieved thats why I used 'may be'

Comment: didnt work... :( even when a delete this: $(function () {$('#<%= ButtonEmail.UniqueID %>').button();}); dont work, the button stays with the original design, but dont work

Comment: is there anyway to recall the button event with click()?