# window.click event issue in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dom, dopostback

I have a common scenario in which when clicking the window dismisses a popup div. The code I use is

```
   $(window).load(function (){
   $('.popupstyle').live("click", function(e){
       return false;
    });
    });
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).click(function(){
   $('.popupstyle').hide();
    });
  });
```

but the problem is that no postback event of controls Like LinkButton  is working on popup div then. return false in click event of the popup div creates a problem.It fuses everything on popuop div. Don't understand what to do fixing one thing disturbs the other. also the live event does not work on first click.  Any suggestions

Comment: That's a common issue, look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757232/jquery-ui-dialog-with-asp-net-button-postback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this is event bubbling , where the event from the child element bubbles to the parent element..

One way of preventing this is to use **e.stopPropagation()** when you encounter the target element

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5PZdh/)

Answer (score 0):

@sushanth is right. Its because of event bubbling, which is an important core js concept. And while it can trip you up in situations with 2 listeners (`$('.popupstyle').live("click"`, `$(window).click`) we can also use bubbling to our advantage and perform the same task with a single listener (`$(window).click`).

```
  $(window).click(function(e){
       if( ! $(e.target).hasClass('popupstyle') ){ $('.popupstyle').hide(); } 
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2Wg3e/1/)