# Setting dialog to modal and appending to form causes dialog box to be modal too

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

The title is self-explanatory; when I append the dialog box to a form and set it as modal, it makes the dialog box modal as well.  Using jQuery UI - v1.10.0

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    hide: "puff",
    appendTo: "form",
    width: '350px'
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear dispite your statement otherwise.  `modal: true,` - yes, it is a modal dialog box so with this limited information there is really no question here, only a statement.

Comment: The question is, why is the dialog box also modal?  I.E. i cannot click the close button in the dialog box because it is modal.  But if i DON'T append the dialog box to the form, then all works as it should, the page is modal, but the dialog box IS NOT.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery UI dialog box, is grayed out too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631819/jquery-ui-dialog-box-is-grayed-out-too)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14787020

It work for me.

```
.ui-dialog
{
    z-index: 101;
}
```