# ASP.NET popup to disappear without at postback

Tags: asp.net, popup, postback

I am looking for a pop-up solution similar to this or just this (http://rayyagubyan9.wordpress.com/2013/10/27/popup-control-for-asp-net/) but is not the version specified more fully available (only the demo).

Are there other possibilities to make?

Comment: why not use jquery ui dilogue? https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ though there will be a learning curve, but it will make your life more easier. I now prefer jquery over ajaxtool kit

Answer (score 1):

I think best solution is to used jQuery Popup. You can easily use that with asp.net code and its open source so you don't need to purchase anything.

Following is a similar kind of example

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-jQuery-Modal-Popup-Window-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: You'll want to use the appendTo: "form" option so that controls placed in the dialog will support postbacks.

Comment: Not understand what you said?

Comment: If you place a user control (such as a button) inside a jQuery Dialog, by default it won't be able to postback. The jQuery team in v1.10 added the appendTo option so that the dialog will be part of the form and thus postbacks will work. The old solution was to get a reference to the dialog and the parent and manually add it. That's what the Accepted Answer is on [jQuery UI dialog with ASP.NET button postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757232/jquery-ui-dialog-with-asp-net-button-postback) but the appendTo option has since been added and is much cleaner. See the answer by @user2100025

Comment: I think this question has same requirement

Comment: So, I have the PopUp from the first Answer. But now I want to Open the Popup about a Button and after an Postback by an Dropdownlist in the PopUp also have to been there.

Now I have these:
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[id*=btnPopup]").live("click", function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }).parent().appendTo('form');;
</script>
But these dosnt work.
Can you help me?