# Kendo Window does not firing server side button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

I use in my Project telerik kendo ui, so I use kendo window, but button which inside kendo window does not firing click event. I try multiple different style but it seems not working. here my window html. and some javascript.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="input-group">
             <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUpgradePrice" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
             <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
             <asp:Button Text="SendITTTT" CssClass="btn btn-danger" ID="btnSendNewPrice" runat="server" OnClick="btnSendNewPrice_Click" />
             <asp:LinkButton Text="Send it" CssClass="btn btn-danger" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="btnSendPrice" OnClick="btnSendNewPrice_Click" runat="server" />

         </div>
         <br />                                   
     </div>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {var myWindow3 = $("#myModalNew").kendoWindow({
            modal: true,
            width: "800px",
            draggable: false,
            visible: false,
            resizable: false,
        }).data("kendoWindow");

        $("#openBtn").on("click", function () {
            myWindow3.center();
            myWindow3.open();
        });

        $("#newModelClose").on("click", function () {
            myWindow3.close();
        });  });
    function ShowLabel() {
        // Note that the client ID might be different from the server side ID
        document.getElementById('lblPriceState').style.display = 'inherit';
    }
</script>
```

Do you have any information about kendo block server side in asp.net..

Comment: I don't see your javascript code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found answer.
I did some research and you know kendo window and jquery dialog work. Anyway, the problem which identified in here [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757232/jquery-ui-dialog-with-asp-net-button-postback) is same so if you put your javascript like this

```
 var myWindow2 = $("#myModal").kendoWindow({
            modal: true,
            width: "800px",
            draggable: false,
            visible: false,
            resizable: false,
            iframe: false //<-- Iframe set to false
        }).data("kendoWindow");

        var modal2 = $("#myModal").kendoWindow();
        modal2.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));//Added this line
```

now server side button which inside kendo window firing click event...,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your `kendoWindow` remove the iframe option like:

```
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
  content: "http://ticodificando.com/",
  iframe: false
});
```

Or from your example above:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var myWindow3 = $("#myModalNew").kendoWindow({
            modal: true,
            width: "800px",
            draggable: false,
            visible: false,
            resizable: false,
            iframe: false //<-- Iframe set to false
        }).data("kendoWindow");
...
```

Comment: It does not work, but it's weird because when I but linkbutton instead of button click is firing, but that time For example, textbox.text come null. Thanks for answer