# can't get selected state of a items of asp.net checked list box while mannul post back

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

```
function CountrySelect(uniqueID) {

        var dialog_buttons = {};
        dialog_buttons['Save'] = function () { __doPostBack('chkcountries', ''); }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                var dlg = $("#dialog").dialog({
                    maxWidth: 400,
                    maxHeight: 500,
                    width: 400,
                    height: 500,

                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons:dialog_buttons,
                    title:"Country Selection dialog",
                    close: CloseFunction
                    ,
                    show: {
                        effect: "Clip",
                        duration: 1000
                    },
                    hide: {
                        effect: "fade",
                        duration: 1000
                    }
                });
```

and markup for div with id dialog is

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none">
        <p>Select Countries</p>
        <p>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkcountries"  runat="server">                   
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </p>
```

and in cs file code is

```
 foreach (ListItem val in chkcountries.Items)
   {
       if (val.Selected == true)
        {

        }
   }
```

problem is on postback it says no item is checked. why

i am not able to get the checked state of checkbox list items.

```
val.selected=false
```

always

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't create comments yet, so I have to do this in an answer.  We need to see the code for populating "chkcountries".  I think you are doing it in your page load event and not checking if you're in a postback when you do that.  So every time the page loads (including postbacks) your checkboxes get reloaded, thus none of them are checked.

Please post your page_load code or wherever you are loading your checkbox list control.

Comment: i am doing this in
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
//Code for ddl bind 
}

Answer (score 0):

Add these property in your checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkcountries" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Setting `EnableViewState` to true will preserve the state of control on postback

Comment: viewstate is enabled for all controls on page.
moreover when i postback througn asp.net controls then it works good.
i think theres something i am missing with this mannaul postback with Javascript.

Comment: this is how i am doing postback
 dialog_buttons['Save'] = function () { __doPostBack('chkcountries', ''); }

Comment: Try adding `runat` attribute to your `dialog_button['Save']`

Comment: i dont think jquery ui dialoge buttons supports runat="server" attribute
Can you post a workin snippet?

Comment: Just check **[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757232/jquery-ui-dialog-with-asp-net-button-postback)** you might get some idea.. :)